# JNI stdout is not print to the console

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, stdout

I use JNI because I need some c libraries.
My problem is that not all is printed to the stdout.
I know I can do

```
puts("test");
fflush(stdout);
```

by myself. But my problem is that the c library has a debug function which prints to the stdout and therefore is not visible in the console. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to stdout because JNI runs the native code from within the Java code, and is not attached to the stdout.
You  can use the following function to write directly to the console device.

```
void console_printf(const char *fmt,...)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY);
    char buffer[1000];
    if (fd < 0)
        return;

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsprintf(buffer, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    close(fd);
}
```